# bash shell script with parameters " \"

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm a newbie in Linux.
I can run this command directly in Terminal:

```
7za t -p' \' -w -y /root/test2.7z | grep -i OK
```

I trying a script (named test_script.sh) for 7zip file password testing:

```
7za t -p$1 -w -y /root/test2.7z | grep -i OK
```

but cannot get result with this script:

```
sh /root/test_script.sh ' \'
```

Update running result:

```
[root@localhost ~]# sh /root/test_script.sh ' \'
7za t -p \ -w -y /root/test2.7z | grep -i OK
ERROR: No more files
\
System ERROR:
Unknown error 18446744071562526744

[root@localhost ~]# sh /root/test_script.sh " \"
> 
> 
>
```

Terminal hanging, maybe waiting a next command.

Please help me how to pass the parameters " \".

Comment: `-p"$1"`. Surely you've run into this suggestion in your research.

Comment: Also, http://shellcheck.net is your friend for detecting such errors...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rici.
The script worked.
    7za t -p"$1" -w -y /root/test2.7z | grep -i OK
Run
    sh /root/test_script.sh ' \'